# CSS and JS - Extend background image beyond div

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm currently trying to find a workaround to having arrows on Niall Doherty's Coda Slider 2 to highlight the selected tab. Initially I tried doing this with images on the header image, although whilst it looked fine in Safari on my Mac, it wasn't central on other devices (see [www.lukekendalldesign.co.uk/pss/productsandservices](http://www.lukekendalldesign.co.uk/pss/productsandservices))

I tried creating this using CSS arrows but that proved rather difficult, so I've found a workaround using a background image, but I've come across yet another problem.

http://cl.ly/HovO (Sorry, I can't upload images - newbie!)

Please refer to the above linked screenshot. The lighter grey triangle that matches the background is part of the header image. The black triangle is positioned using the following CSS code:

```
.coda-nav ul li a.current { 
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
    color: white;
    height: 60px; 
    z-index: 20000;
    background: url(../images/triangle.png) no-repeat 50% 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is position this black arrow where the grey image arrow is (if that makes sense at all?) How can I do this?

I have tried adding margins and padding, however it extends the grey background and doesn't push the background image black triangle down.

Whilst I have found solutions similar, none seem to apply because the class .current is applied using the following JS:

```
// If we need a tabbed nav
    $('#coda-nav-' + sliderCount + ' a').each(function(z) {
        // What happens when a nav link is clicked
        $(this).bind("click", function() {
            navClicks++;
            $(this).addClass('current').parents('ul').find('a').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
            offset = - (panelWidth*z);
            alterPanelHeight(z);
            currentPanel = z + 1;
            $('.panel-container', slider).animate({ marginLeft: offset }, settings.slideEaseDuration, settings.slideEaseFunction);
            if (!settings.crossLinking) { return false }; // Don't change the URL hash unless cross-linking is specified
        });
    });
```

I would very much appreciate any help anyone can offer me on this - as it's a JS issue it's something that's a bit out of my depth! :(

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in Firefox using fire bug on windows. I think there are 2 problems. The first is that the margin on the ul element should be 167px (the black arrow is not in a nice place in the image (middle is at 232 px did you mean this?).
The the arrow just needs moving down which I did by setting the back ground position to be:
url("../images/triangle.png") no-repeat scroll 50px 60px transparent hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks John - with regard to the 167px, are you referring to the horizontal positioning? If so, this is set to 50% because I need to ensure it's in the centre for each tab - the width of each tab varies depending on the title.

I've just done the second edits you mentioned, however now I can't see the arrow at all?

Comment: The 167px is for the ul element styling. It reads: .coda-nav ul margin-left: 170px which should be 167px or the arrow in the image needs to be moved. Sorry you are right I thought I had lined it up but I just got rid of it, doh! I should be more careful. I will have a but more thought.

Comment: Ah I see, I've edited the 167px now, thanks. This arrow is bugging me so much!

Comment: Sorry the answer above is not right. I am not sure what the answer is I will think on it but hopefully someone else will answer you first. My current idea is to try to add a div with the image in then position it absolutely in the box but I couldn't make it overflow properly.